# Fullcalendar: How to merge two events that are next to each other?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

In my case I very often have users that instead of clicking and dragging to create a long event (day view), just click in one time slot (30 min), then click the next one (30 min).

So instead of an event 13:00 - 14:00 I get first 13:00-13:30 and second 13:30-14:00.

To prevent this I would like to merge both events into one so that they show up as 13:00 - 14:00.

[image: fullcalendar merge events]

How to do that properly?

Answer (score 10):

This is how I finally solved it:

```
// user choses event
select: function (start, end, jsEvent, view) 
{
    var diffmin = (new Date(end).getTime()/1000 - new Date(start).getTime()/1000)/60;
    var title = diffmin+' min';
    var eventData;
    // some users click 1 slot, then the following, so we have 2 events each 30 min instead of 60 min
    // merge both events into one
    var eventmerge = false;
    $.each(allevents, function( index, eventitem )
    {
        if(eventitem!==null && typeof eventitem != 'undefined')
        {
            // if start time of new event (2nd slot) is end time of existing event (1st slot)
            if( moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm') == moment(eventitem.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm') )
            {
                eventmerge = true;
                // existing event gets end data of new merging event
                eventitem.end = end;
            }
            // if end time of new event (1st slot) is start time of existing event (2nd slot)
            else if( moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm') == moment(eventitem.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm') )
            {
                eventmerge = true;
                // existing event gets start data of new merging event
                eventitem.start = start;
            }

            if(eventmerge)
            {
                // recalculate
                var diffmin = (new Date(eventitem.end).getTime()/1000 - new Date(eventitem.start).getTime()/1000)/60;
                eventitem.title = diffmin+' min';

                // copy to eventData
                eventData = eventitem;

                // find event object in calendar
                var eventsarr = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
                $.each(eventsarr, function(key, eventobj) { 
                    if(eventobj._id == eventitem.id) {
                        console.log('merging events');
                        eventobj.start = eventitem.start;
                        eventobj.end = eventitem.end;
                        eventobj.title = eventitem.title;
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', eventobj);
                    }
                });

                // break each loop
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
    if(!eventmerge)
    {
        // console.log('adding event id: '+eventcount);
        eventData = {
            id: eventcount, // identifier
            title: title,
            start: start,
            end: end,
            color: '#00AA00',
            editable: true,
            eventDurationEditable: true,
        };

        // register event in array
        allevents[eventcount] = eventData;
        eventcount++;

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true);
    }

    // console.log(start, end);
    setTimePrice(eventData);

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
},
```

**Result:**

[image: result fullcalendar merge]

**Example Result:**

[FullCalendar at Matheboss.de](https://www.matheboss.de/booking?tutorid=3208)