# How to merge (and collapse / expand) similar events in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar

I'm trying to find a way to collapse events that have the same titles, and have overlapping start and end times.  This is using FullCalendar js ([FullCalendar.io](https://fullcalendar.io)).

This is so that when a person loads the calendar, the duplicate events are collapsed together but with a caret (triangle) that shows the events can be expanded out.

Looking at the docs for FullCalendar, I haven't found any methods to do this directly.  I have found a similar question on StackOverflow that shows a calendar merging events when they are within 30 minutes of each other, but wasn't able to adapt that code to get what I wanted ([Fullcalendar: How to merge two events that are next to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34606866/fullcalendar-how-to-merge-two-events-that-are-next-to-each-other)).  That also puts the two events into the same event, which isn't exactly what I want to do.

I've tried modifying the code in the other question, and also looking to see if I could perhaps take the elements and add classes to them with jQuery to get the similar events, but the problem is that the events are on different rows, and don't seem to be predictable where the next one would be.

I've also considered trying to do something like add a `<details><summary>Duplicate Event Titles</summary></details>` tag around the duplicates, which will collapse them and show them with a caret, but they are on different rows and I am not sure that will work because the html would need to wrap around unrelated rows and also collapse those.

Unmerged:
[Unmerged Events with the same title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3npga.png)

Test case showing duplicate events (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QYQOwy)

Comment: "looking to see if I could perhaps take the elements and add classes to them with jQuery to get the similar events, but the problem is that the events are on different rows" ... I'm not sure how the events being on different rows would affect your ability to use classes to associate them together?

Comment: If you have some property of the event whose value it shares with all its duplicates (e.g. the same ID, or some custom property you introduce for this purpose), then during the eventRender callback you could add a CSS class to the event which is unique to that property value. e.g. if the property is "id: 20" then add a class "id-20" for all events whose ID is 20. Then when you come to collapse the event you can simply look for all other events which have the same class, and apply the same action.